# Keycloak long-lived sessions

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak, openid-connect

At work we're currently in the process of migrating a legacy auth system for our mobile backends to Keycloak. We've got most of the changes working following the documentation, and have setup Keycloak to use a MySQL DB for its data along with running it in an HA configuration with 3 replicas. `CACHE_OWNERS_COUNT` is set to 3 so that cached data is available across multiple replicas.

For our mobile apps, once a user has logged in, we want them to stay logged in regardless of what ends up happening on the auth server side, ie once a session is created it should persist across Keycloak restarts/upgrades etc. Reading the docs it seems like user sessions are only backed by cache, and not persisted. If we ever migrate Keycloak to a new cluster or need to upgrade, it seems like all our users will get logged out? Am I understanding this correctly?

Is there a way to have Keycloak sessions stay active across server restarts? I came across offline sessions/tokens but I'm not sure if that's considered a safe approach. There are some discussions in the mailing lists but haven't come across anything concrete, unless I've totally missed something. Any pointers welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: That is actually a very interesting question. I would also be interested to know because of high availability concerns